# RadHtmlChart not showing data from a datatable source

Tags: c#, telerik, radhtmlchart

This is really a simple bar chart that I want to show.

Here is my chart:

```
 <telerik:RadHtmlChart runat="server" ID="Chart_WarrantiesByMonth" Width="800" Height="500" Transitions="true">
                    <Appearance>
                        <FillStyle BackgroundColor="White"></FillStyle>
                    </Appearance>
                    <ChartTitle Text="Warranties By Month">
                    </ChartTitle>
                </telerik:RadHtmlChart>
```

Here is my databinding call

```
DataTable chartSource = new DataTable();
        MySqlCommand mysqlcmdChart = new MySqlCommand();
        mysqlcmdChart.CommandText = "_DealerPortal_Chart_WarrantiesByMonth";
        mysqlcmdChart.Parameters.AddWithValue("DealershipIdParam", DealershipIdParam);
        chartSource = MySQLProcessing.MySQLProcessor.DataTable_StoredProcedure(mysqlcmdChart,mysqlCon,CommandType.StoredProcedure);

        Chart_WarrantiesByMonth.DataSource = chartSource;
        Chart_WarrantiesByMonth.PlotArea.XAxis.DataLabelsField = "Date";
        Chart_WarrantiesByMonth.PlotArea.XAxis.Name = "Date";
        Chart_WarrantiesByMonth.PlotArea.YAxis.Name = "Warranties";
        Chart_WarrantiesByMonth.DataBind();
```

I've made sure my chart has data;

```
Warranties  Date
1   August 2014
13  December 2013
40  February 2014
8   January 2014
13  March 2014
1   May 2015
```

This is really frustrating and i'ts making me scream.  No matter what I do, I cannot get the chart to show anything other than this:  One thing is i'm doing a simple asp button onbutton click to execute the databind.  I'm expecting my x axis to be the month/year and y to be the count.   Thanks!

Thanks!

[image: My chart]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to have a series defined: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/htmlchart/examples/functionality/dateaxis/defaultcs.aspx. Otherwise, what data is the chart supposed to show? By the looks of it, you need a LineSeries (like in that demo) and its DataFieldY property should be set to "Warranties"